# How to use ngModel with a custom control inside a form?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I created a component for handling select box, now when I put it in form tag after submitted form the result of the selection doesn't show up in console.

What's the problem with my code? how can I fix this?

- testOption: is array of object I passed throw the select box with `@Input`.

**here is select box component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'input-select',
    template:`
      <div class="field-select">
        <span><icon name="select-arrow" size="10"></icon></span>
        <select name="{{name}}" class="field">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>{{label}}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    `
})
export class InputSelectComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() options;


    // testOptions = [
    //   {value:'test',name:'test2'},
    //   {value:'test',name:'test2'}
    // ];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.options);
     }

}
```

**Usage in html:**

```html
<input-select label="test" name="select2" [options]="testOption"></input-select>
```

**form html:**

```html
<form role="form" class="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
    <input class="field" name="name" ngModel type="text" placeholder="n1">
    <input-select label="b2" name="select2" [options]="testObject"></input-select>
    <input class="field" name="building-type" type="text" ngModel placeholder="b3">
</form>
```

**console log:** (there is no select box value)

```
Object {name: "test", building-type: "tset" }
```

Comment: You talk about `testOption` and `testObject`. Whats the correct name? :) Check that first..

Comment: @mxii the correct name is testOption. my bad :)

Comment: Show your "parent" component please. (template)

Comment: It logs `undefined` to the console? what do you mean with `result of selection`. I dont see any code that would print the result to console. :)

Comment: @mxii i updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I got your problem now.

You want to implement `ControlValueAccessor` on your custom component to use it inside of a form with `ngModel`!?

Your component should look like this:

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'ng2-input-select',
   template: `
      <div class="field-select">
        <select name="{{ name }}" class="field" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="_onChange($event)">
          <option value="" disabled selected>{{ label }}</option>
          <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{ option.name }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
   `,
   providers: [
      { /* idk why or what this will do exactly.. but it works! ;) */
         provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
         useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectBoxComponent),
         multi: true
      }
   ]
})
export class SelectBoxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() options;
  @Input() value: string = '';

  // ControlValueAccessor implementation
  // ====================================

  // call if value was changed inside our component
  private _onChange = (_: any) => { };
  // call if input was "touched" .. !
  private _onTouched = () => { };

  // incoming change..
  public writeValue(val: any) {
    this.value = val;
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this._onChange = fn; }
  public registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this._onTouched = fn; }
}
```

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/imCJmCoJaeGQiUMcyBwz?p=preview

**UPDATE**

Using change detection in your form-component:

```html
<ng2-input-select ngModel (ngModelChange)="selectBoxChanged($event)" label="b2" name="select2" [options]="testObject"></ng2-input-select>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have another question, how can I call `registerOnChange` function in another component?

Comment: Why should you do this? :) What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to detect change of select box with different component and and also with different object. basically I wanna use `registerOnChange` function.

Comment: You shouldn't use this functions.. See my updated answer for change-detection. Its the same as with other form-inputs using `ngModel`.

Comment: Hi @mxii I am wondering why is the controlvalueaccessor method used instead of another type of component communication?  like services or viewchild or inputs and outputs.  Can you elaborate on this question?  perhaps I should just put it as a question.

Comment: Cause he wants to use this component inside of a form. and with this ControlValueAccessor angular forms will work like normal.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, using Angular 5.. I still get `ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead`

Answer (score 0):

try `[value]="option.value"`, btw could you show your console too

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind ngModel as one of the attributes in your selector.then print the ngModel value in your console.

Comment: after binding ngModel on component selector I got this error: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'select2'`

Comment: You have to include forms in your selector.
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms'.