# ngModelChange get called on keypress even though not fired from ngModelChange.emit()

Tags: angular

I'm trying to call the ngModelChange event but only when I call it with

```
this.ngModelChange.emit(data)
```

Now it's being called every time I hit a key on my keyboard and when I call it with the previous command. Why?

I have a component 'Feild' in which I create different types of input depending of a type attribute passed. One of them is an autocomplete component that I created in JQuery. In order to make it work with angular, I created a component to pass the value to it.

Field component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `<div class="field">
                <div class="fieldTitle" *ngIf="text">{{text}}</div>
                <div class="fieldValue" *ngIf="type">
                    <input *ngIf="type == 'text'" type="text" [ngModel]="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [name]="name" ngDefaultControl/>
                    <autocomplete *ngIf="type == 'autocomplete'" [link]="link" [mapping]="mapping" [ngModel]="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [name]="name" ngDefaultControl></autocomplete>
                </div>
            </div>`
})
export class Field{
    @Input() text: string;
    @Input() type: string;
    @Input() ngModel: any;
    @Input() name: string;
    @Input() mapping: string;
    @Input() link: string;

    @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){

    }

    onChange(e){
        this.ngModel = e;
        this.ngModelChange.emit(e);
    }
}
```

Autocomplete component:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete',
  template: `<div #autocomplete class='autoComplete'></div>`
})
export class AutoComplete{
    @Input() ngModel: any;
    @Input() link: string;
    @Input() mapping: string;

    @ViewChild('autocomplete') content: any;

    @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() select = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(){

    }
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        var ctrl = this;
        var options = {
            link: this.link,
            mapping: this.mapping,
            data: this.ngModel,

            onSelect: function(data: any){
                ctrl.ngModel = data;
                ctrl.ngModelChange.emit(data);
                ctrl.select.emit({data: data});
            },
            setData: function(e : any){
                ctrl.ngModel = e;
                ctrl.ngModelChange.emit(e);
            }
        }

        for(var key in options) {
            if(options[key] === undefined){
                delete options[key];
            }
        }

        $(this.content.nativeElement).autoComplete(options);
    }
}
```

My autocomplete generates an input with some other divs and style. When I type something inside, it filters a list of data and show only those that mathes the string inside the input. When I click on a result, it sets the data with the one I clicked. On every keypress it calls setData(undefined) to remove the data and on a click event it calls the function onSelect(data). That part works just fine.

What does'nt work, is that the function onChange() from the Field component gets called on every keystrokes with the value in string of the input before the the function setData() from the Autocomplete component. How do I remove the unwanted call to onChange()?

Thanks in advance

You can go check at the plunker tor an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/jAVIupQ2R1Vm1y9YHoLI?p=preview

If you look in the console, you will see the string and undefined. The string is the samething as in the input and the undefined what the autocomplete returns. The undefined is good but not the string. It took me a while to make it work. It turns out that this happens as soon as you import FormsModule. I need FormsModule to since I use other kind of input that works with NgModel.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

Do NOT use reserved angular words like `ngModelChange` nor `ngModel`.

Seems like it will lead to unexpected behaviors!!

**Second:**

Your `autocomplete` isn't working correct, it won't set the current value.

fixed it:

```js
obj.search = function (reinitialize) {
   obj.options.data = obj.input[0].value; // NEW !!
      if (reinitialize === true) {
         //obj.options.data = undefined; // ?!?!?!? WHY ??
```

here's a working demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/2H0GRSp3ktJWoMSWDe7S?p=preview

**Third:**

It would be better to implement the right `ngModel` support. You have to implement the `ControlValueAccessor`, like described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935754/3631348

Comment: It's not working since onChange get called twice. Once for the keypress with a param of string and the second time from the this.ngModelChange.emit(data).

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a plunker?

Comment: I've updated my question to add the plunker and some few explanations.

Comment: See my updated answer. There was an error in your autocomplete.js and some weird behaviors using some "wrong" angular-names.

Comment: It's not what I need. I think you did'nt understand exactly what I want. 

What a want is if the user write something in the field, the value in ngModel get set to undefined, not the text! And if the user click on on of the items returned from the autocomplete plugin, it get sets with the object assossiated with that line he clicked on. Right now, the value is always the string in the input, which is not good.

Comment: How to feat your plugin with suggestions? I never got some values to select.. please update your plunker to got some autocomplete if typing `te` or something..

Comment: It does'nt matter if you have something to select or not, because the problem is before you select something, but as you requested, I've updated my plunker.

Comment: Thanks, you want it like this, right? https://plnkr.co/edit/MwhStfLsumz74lG9311l?p=preview

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you. So to conclude, I cannot use ngModelChange with a custom component with an input with nbModel on that one if I have included FormsModule. I have to use another custom event to do the same job otherwise ngModelChange will be called by angular automaticaly.